# ValueError Django model.Manager.get function

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to overload the get function in the below code...

```
class QuizzerBotManager(models.Manager):

    def create_quizzer_bot(self):
        quizzer_bot = self.create(
            client_data=None,
            should_set_name = False,
            should_set_age = False,
            should_set_gender = False,
            quiz = None,
            quiz_length = 0,
            should_set_quiz = False,
            should_check_postback = False,
            should_check_message = True,
            should_check_answer = False,
            question_number = 0,
            score = 0
        )
        quizzer_bot.answer_statuses = []
        return quizzer_bot

    def get_quizzer_bot(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            quizzer_bot = self.get(args, kwargs)
            quizzer_bot.answer_statuses = json.loads(quizzer_bot.answers)

        except ProgrammingError:
            quizzer_bot = self.create_quizzer_bot()

        return quizzer_bot
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

The stack shows that this error occurs where I try to call `self.get(args, kwargs)`.
Why is this? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing your `args` and `kwargs` correctly. Try this instead:

```
quizzer_bot = self.get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe it was something so basic. But help me understand... Doesn't the * simply signify unpacking the list?

Comment: with `args` you're passing the arguments as a tuple. However, the function does not take tuples. But with `*args`, the function can't tell the difference between a *regular* call with all the arguments placed and this (`*args`).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass those parameters on with the relevant unpacking operators:

```
quizzer_bot = self.get(*args, **kwargs)
```